# Menu create in admin panel function.php through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom themes and created a new function.php, but menu doesn't display in admin panel.

This is my code:

```
register_nav_menus(
array( 'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'blankslate' ),
       'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' ),
       'extra-menu2' => __( 'Extra Menu 2' ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Comment: use this  add_action( 'init', 'register_nav_menus' );

Comment: I have already try like This..

 add_action( 'init', 'register_nav_menus' );

Comment: You created "a new function.php" what do you mean? You need to use the _functions.php_ of your theme, or if you create a new file for your functions you need to include it in _functions.php_, otherwise how Wordpress could know he should use functions in this file...?

Answer (score 1):

This should be your function

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'menu-name' => __( 'Menu Display Name' ),
      'menu-name' => __( 'Menu Display Name' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Comment: I Know change function name but ,and try it but not fix issues.

Comment: suppose i want to create new theme so i have need some file like style.css index,header....same here create function.php and add include my above code for menu but i think function.php not working in my theme....plz help me

Comment: what is your file name??it should be functions.php

Comment: ohh...yes i have missing name  
function instead of functions...

Thank You Very Much Dear....

Comment: Thanks :) if my answer helped you please upvote my answer.